# 10GB connectivity between Amazon Instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

I am trying to architect a solution for Amazon EC2 that requires high network bandwidth.  Is there a way to provision 10GbE connectivity between Amazon ec2 instances to get high network bandwidth?

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen official stats for ec2 network throughput, but assuming (and that's a big assumption) it's similar to the RDS values https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/ you're going to end up paying a lot of money for 10Gbit, the only instance that provides it is db.r3.8xlarge.

Comment: The only "official" mention of 10Gb a quick google shows up with regards to ec2 is on the FAQ: "CG1 instances provide customers with high bandwidth 10 Gbps networking"  https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

Certain Amazon EC2 instances types launched into the same cluster placement group are placed into a non-blocking 10 Gigabit ethernet network.

These instance types include:

- m4.10xlarge
- c4.8xlarge
- c3.8xlarge
- g2.8xlarge
- r3.8xlarge
- d2.8xlarge
- i2.8xlarge
- cc2.8xlarge
- cc1.4xlarge
- cr1.8xlarge

Just look in the **Network Performance** column in the EC2 launch console and you'll see it says "10 Gigabit".

From the [Placement Groups documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html):

> A *placement group* is a logical grouping of instances within a single Availability Zone. Using placement groups enables applications to participate in a low-latency, 10 Gbps network. Placement groups are recommended for applications that benefit from low network latency, high network throughput, or both.
>
> To provide the lowest latency, and the highest packet-per-second network performance for your placement group, choose an instance type that supports *enhanced networking*.

The following instances [support enhanced networking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html#enhanced_networking_instance_types): C3, C4, D2, I2, M4, R3